# If $A=\int_{0}^{1} x^n(1-x)^ndx$ then $A^{-1} \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

Consider the integral $$A=\int_{0}^{1} x^n(1-x)^ndx$$ Prove that $A^{-1}$ is a natural number.
I have no idea how to compute the integral. But by putting $n=1$ I got $A^{-1}=6$ a natural number. Is there any simple method to show that $A^{-1}$ is a natural number?

Comment: A rather simple way to evaluate the integral is performing integration by parts $n$ times. Each time the primitive part vanishes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:
\begin{align}\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n\,dx&=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}(1-x)^n\big|^{1}_{0}+\frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1x^{n+1}(1-x)^{n-1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1x^{n+1}(1-x)^{n-1}\,dx
\end{align}
now you repeat the process $n$ times so to get
$$\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n\,dx=\frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdots 1}{(n+1)\cdot (n+2) \cdots 2 n}\int_0^1x^{2n}\,dx=\frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdots 1}{(n+1)\cdot (n+2) \cdots 2n\cdot (2n+1)}$$
thus 
$$\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n\,dx=\frac{n!n!}{(2n+1)!}$$
you shall conclude.

Answer (score 5):

There is also a way to interpret this integral as a probability and therefore obtain a closed formula instantly. Imagine choosing $n$ blue, $n$ red and one black point uniformly at random on $[0,1]$. What is the probability that there will be $n$ red, one black and $n$ blue points appearing on this segment in this order? On one hand it is our integral - if $x$ is the coordinate of the black point, $x^n(1-x)^n$ is the probability that $n$ red points will be on the left and $n$ blue points on the right. On the other hand all possible arrangements are equally likely - there are $(2n+1)!$ of them in total and $(n!)^2$ of them result in the required order. 
It also generalizes nicely and allows to compute values of a Beta function for all positive integer values.

Comment: Very nice, was trying to find a probability argument.

Comment: So, $A^{-1}$ is equal to the number of sequences in $\{ \mathrm{red}, \mathrm{blue}, \mathrm{black} \}^{2n+1}$ in which red and blue each appear $n$ times, and black appears 1 time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) to prove $$A^{-1}=\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!^2}=(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}.$$

Comment: And to cut to the chase, so to speak, one possible proof of that involves evaluating the double integral $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty x^n y^n e^{-(x+y)} \,dy \,dx$ in two different ways.

Answer (score 2):

$$A=\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n\mathrm dx=B(n+1,n+1)=\frac{\Gamma^2(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+2)}=\frac1{(2n+1)\binom{2n}n}$$
Thus,
$$A=\frac1{(2n+1)\binom{2n}n}~\implies~A^{-1}=(2n+1)\binom{2n}n$$

> $$\therefore~A^{-1}\in\Bbb N$$

Here we have applied the integral representation of the [Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) combined with its quite simple relation to the [Gamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html). What remains is to show that the binomial coefficient is always an integer; which is quite fundamental knowledge.

Comment: Careful: $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$.

Comment: @J.G. I haven't done enought math for to long; sorry, I will fix this.